# Create a timestamp column in Spark dataframe without milliseconds part

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to create a new column called `load_time_stamp` in Pyspark's data frame which should only contain today's date and time till seconds and should not contain milliseconds.

I have written the below code for the same but with this, a new column is getting created with null values and not with the timestamp values which I expected.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

x.withColumn("load_time_stamp", F.to_timestamp(F.substring(F.current_timestamp(), 0, 19), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")).show()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get a timestamp type column with only seconds precision, then you can use `from_unixtime` function.

Example:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

x = spark.createDataFrame([(1,)], ["id"])

x.withColumn(
    "load_time_stamp",
    F.from_unixtime(F.current_timestamp().cast("long"))
).show(truncate=False)

#+---+-------------------+
#|id |load_time_stamp    |
#+---+-------------------+
#|1  |2021-02-22 15:35:34|
#+---+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `date_format` instead:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

x.withColumn("load_time_stamp", F.date_format(F.current_timestamp(), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"))
```

Note that `to_timestamp` converts a timestamp **from** the given format, while `date_format` converts a timestamp **to** the given format. You do not need to `substring` the current timestamp because `date_format` will take care of that when formatting to the desired format.