# Getting incorrect timestamp in Spark SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In code I have

```
date_format(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
```

and the output is `2023-10-16 05:49:15.000`, shouldn't the output be `2023-10-16 05:49:15` ?
Not sure why spark is adding the extra fraction of seconds in the end, I am unable to remove it.

I have tried `date_format(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')`
but still have the same issue

Comment: maybe this could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66315018/create-a-timestamp-column-in-spark-dataframe-without-milliseconds-part

Answer (score 2):

I have check in Spark `3.3.0` & It is truncating last fraction of seconds correctly. Check below.

```
scala> spark
.sql("select date_format(current_timestamp, 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss') as ts ")
.show(false)
+-------------------+
|ts                 |
+-------------------+
|2023-10-17 04:46:52|
+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime

data1 = [   ["1"],
            ["2"],
        ]

df1Columns = ["id"]
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data=data1, schema = df1Columns)
current_datetime = datetime.now()
new_df = df1.withColumn("date", F.date_format(F.lit(current_datetime), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'))
new_df.show(truncate=False)
```

Output :

```
+---+-------------------+
|id |date               |
+---+-------------------+
|1  |2023-10-16 23:57:01|
|2  |2023-10-16 23:57:01|
+---+-------------------+
```